# Shopping Cart Plus Button Consecutively Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a shopping cart, every cart item has plus and minus button.
I need when a user click 3 times (consecutively) plus button then call
addtocart function after latest click. Latest click mean between first click
and third click there is delay time, so user can click 4 times.
How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't try with some counter, each time the user click on the button we sum 1+ to the counter, and when the counter reach 3, we foo something.

here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/142/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Shop" />
```

**JS**

```
var countClick = 0   
    $('#button1').click(function() {
        countClick++
            if(countClick === 3){
               console.log('counter reach ' + countClick)
               var myButton= document.getElementById('button1');
               myButton.style.display ='none';
               setTimeout (function(){
                  myButton.style.display ='inline'; //here we hide the button for 5seconds
               countClick = 0 // here we make the counter go back to 0 again
              },5000);
              //do stuff here like add to cart or something.
             }else{
             console.log('counter still on ' + countClick);
          }
      });
```

Comment: But you didn't consider that there is delay time so user may click only one time or three time.

Comment: How you endend solving this?

Comment: Ethaan your code helped me. Thanks.
I counted clicks and set timet out after first click then I get item quantity.